# Why git keeps ignoring files within certain directory despite I stated it should not

Tags: git

I have setup git under my home assistant directory. The suggest the following configuration:

```
# Example .gitignore file for your config dir.
# An * ensures that everything will be ignored.
*
# You can whitelist files/folders with !, these will not be ignored.
!*.yaml
!.gitignore
!*.md
```

Then I added a couple of whitelist AFTER the git was initialize and several commits were made:

```
# Example .gitignore file for your config dir.
# An * ensures that everything will be ignored.
*
# You can whitelist files/folders with !, these will not be ignored.
!*.yaml
!.gitignore
!*.md
!packages/
!esphome
!syslog-ng/
!python_scripts/**
# Ignore folders.
.storage
```

So the problem is that files under certain directories are still ignored, despite I clearly stated they should not. For example, under python_scripts folder all `.py` files are being ignored. Funny `.yaml` files are not ignored.
I know there are several questions like this, and several answers, but I think my case is different. I think the fact that I whitelisted certain extensions makes git thing that only files with that extension should be unignored.
I can't add `!*.py` to the gitignore because I only want python files under the pythons_scripts folder to be not ignored.

I already tried several variations like `!python_scripts/**/*.py` without luck. And also my real objective is to whitelist the entire folder, all contents.
I even tried to add a `.gitignore` file to that subfolder with the content `!*`, no luck, git keeps saying:

```
➜  config git:(lovelace.yaml) ✗ git add python_scripts/*
The following paths are ignored by one of your .gitignore files:
python_scripts
hint: Use -f if you really want to add them.
hint: Turn this message off by running
hint: "git config advice.addIgnoredFile false"
```

Some extra debugging information.
Git version

```sh
git --version
git version 2.32.0
```

As you can see, if I add a test.py file git says it ignores it because the `*` on the main gitignore, despite the clear `!*` on the nested gitignore.

```
touch python_scripts/test.py
git check-ignore -v python_scripts/test.py
.gitignore:3:*  python_scripts/test.py
python_scripts/.gitignore
!*#
```

However, yaml files that are whitelisted at root are not ignored:

```sh
ls python_scripts
insultar_invitados.py  services.yaml          test.py
git check-ignore -vv python_scripts/services.yaml
# no output
```

OS info:

```
uname -a
Linux a0d7b954-ssh 5.10.70 #1 SMP Mon Oct 4 23:24:22 UTC 2021 x86_64 Linux
cat /etc/alpine-release
3.14.1
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your intention is to ignore all toplevel elements by default, and whitelist some of them, replace `*` with `/*` :

```
# A '/*' will ignore all elements in the current directory,
# but will not apply to sub directories
/*
```

---

The relevant part of [git help gitignore](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore) is in the ["Pattern Format"](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore#_pattern_format) section :

> - If there is a separator at the beginning or middle (or both) of the pattern, then the pattern is relative to the directory level of the particular `.gitignore` file itself. Otherwise the pattern may also match at any level below the `.gitignore` level.

This also applies to `*` :

- with `*` : even if you explicitly named `packages/` in your toplevel gitignore, everything inside this directory is "caught" by that `*` rule ; you would have to add explicit include rules in `packages/.gitignore` (1)
- with `/*` : the "catch all" pattern is only applied to the toplevel directory

---

*(1) extra note* : when testing on my machine (git 2.33.1 running on linux), adding `!*` to `packages/.gitignore` *does* make the content of `packages` "visible" to `git add`.
What git version + OS are you running ? Do you have other `.gitignore` files interfering with that one ?

Here is a command to debug why a file is ignored :

```
git check-ignore -v path/to/file
```

Comment: I updated the question with the debugging info youmentioned. Not sure what other gitignore files may be interfering, but there is just one at the root of the folder and some other on sibling subfolders, but they all have the same content to whitelist the entire folder.

Comment: @Danielo515 : does setting `/*` in the root `.gitignore` file work for you ?

Comment: @Danielo515 : about the content of your `packages/.gitignore` file : is the final `#` present in the actual file ? if yes, this character is part of the pattern (it only counts as a comment marker at the *beginning* of a line)

Comment: No, the `#` is part of the shebang. I'll try the `/*`, and if it works I'll flag your answer as accepted.

Comment: Your proposed solution works. Now I have to add some more lines to some of the nested `.gitignore` files, but that is an acceptable tradeoff.